How do I get a sensible key label from a `PhysicalKeyboardKey` instance in Flutter?
I am trying to make a widget which will allow me to dynamically generate help screens from keyboard shortcuts, but I can only use PhysicalKeyboardKey.debugName in debug mode.
Is there a way I can convert the PhysicalKeyboardKey instance to LogicalKeyboardKey to take advantage of the keyLabel property perhaps?
Here is a stripped down version of the code I have so far:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class KeyboardShortcut {
  /// Create an instance.
  const KeyboardShortcut({
    required this.description,
    required this.key,
    required this.invoke,
    this.controlKey = false,
    this.altKey = false,
    this.shiftKey = false,
  });
  final String description;
  final PhysicalKeyboardKey key;
  final VoidCallback invoke;
  final bool controlKey;
  final bool shiftKey;
  final bool altKey;
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        title: 'Keyboard Shortcuts Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Create an instance.
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  /// Build the widget.
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    final shortcuts = <KeyboardShortcut>[
      KeyboardShortcut(
        description: 'Action 1',
        key: PhysicalKeyboardKey.digit1,
        invoke: () {
          print('Action 1.');
        },
      ),
      KeyboardShortcut(
        description: 'Action 2',
        key: PhysicalKeyboardKey.digit2,
        invoke: () {
          print('Action 2.');
        },
      ),
    ];
    final keyboard = HardwareKeyboard.instance;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Keyboard Shortcuts'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (final listViewContext, final index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            return Focus(
              onKeyEvent: (final node, final event) {
                if (event is KeyRepeatEvent) {
                  return KeyEventResult.ignored;
                }
                for (final shortcut in shortcuts) {
                  if (shortcut.key == event.physicalKey &&
                      shortcut.controlKey == keyboard.isControlPressed &&
                      shortcut.altKey == keyboard.isAltPressed &&
                      shortcut.shiftKey == keyboard.isShiftPressed) {
                    if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
                      shortcut.invoke();
                    }
                    return KeyEventResult.handled;
                  }
                }
                return KeyEventResult.ignored;
              },
              autofocus: true,
              child: const ListTile(
                title: Text('Keyboard area'),
              ),
            );
          }
          final shortcut = shortcuts[index - 1];
          final key = shortcut.key.debugName ?? 'RELEASE MODE';
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(key),
            subtitle: Text(shortcut.description),
            onTap: shortcut.invoke,
          );
        },
        itemCount: shortcuts.length + 1,
        shrinkWrap: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}

I'd rather not add a keyDescription property to KeyboardShortcut if I don't have to.
Thank you all in advance.
